# ios Application Preference calls

Tags: ios

I've set up my application settings bundle to have two text boxes to hold an ip address and port number. However, when I run my code with non hardcoded ip address and port numbers, nothing happens.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

At the top of my code I define my identifiers. These are straight copied and pasted from the identifier boxes in the Root.plist

```
#define k_ip_address @"ip_address"
#define k_port_address @"port_number"
```

Then in the code where I connect to the ip address and port number I have the following lines:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *host = [defaults objectForKey:k_ip_address];// HOST;
uint16_t port = [defaults objectForKey:k_port_address];// PORT;
```

But when I try to run my new program with these modifications nothing happens but if I revert back to the hardcoded version, my code works fine.

Am I using user defaults wrong?

Image of my Root.plist
[image]

Comment: Can you put the code of how you store thoSE values in the NSUSerDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values that are stored in the plist are not the values that you will see in the NSUserDefaults. for the NSUserDefaults you need to store the data programatically.

To solve your problem I see two solutions:

a) Store the data in NSUSerDefaults programatically and forget about the .plist:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:MY_IP forKey: k_ip_address];
[defaults synchronize];
```

b) Forget about the NSUserDefaults and write/read from the .plist:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Root"
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second option is what I want to achieve. But how can I use that with the code sample I put up? Could you please post an example?

Comment: REad the value of dict and you'll see there the value of the plist